# groovy typesafe configurations with ConfigObject and ConfigSlurper

Tags: groovy, configuration, ide, static-typing

I am using a groovy configuration file and parse it with ConfigSlurper resulting in a ConfigObject that I use for accessing my configuration. The disadvantage is that I have no help from eclipse regarding if properties exist - every configuration property is underlined as groovy/eclipse do not know which properties the (dynamic) ConfigObject has. Refactoring is also not possible - for example if I rename a property in the config, groovy/eclipse does not recognise its usages in the sourcecode and does not rename it there.

Are there ways to fix or workaround these two issues?

Answer (score -1):

[Groovy-eclipse DSL Descriptors](http://groovy.codehaus.org/DSL+Descriptors+for+Groovy-Eclipse) come to mind:

[image: DSL example]

Also, [`@TypeChecked` extensions](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Type+checking+extensions) may be used if you want type safety in your DSL.